# Correct way to integrate a Python module into my code (Hg, Google Code)

Tags: python, mercurial

I had a custom script programmed and it is using the authors own module that is hosted on Google code in a Mercurial repo. I understand how to clone the repo but this will just stick the source into a folder on my computer. Is there a proper way to add the module into my python install to make it available for my projects? (e.g. with modules hosted on pypi you can use virtualenv and pip to install).

Thanks
Dave O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In exactly the same way. Just pass the address of the repo to `pip install`, using the `-e` parameter:

```
pip install -e hg+http://code.google.com/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the module isn't on pypi, clone the repository with Hg and see if there's a setup.py file.  If there is, open a command prompt, cd to that directory, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: There wasn't one included but I did see that option on the Python manual page for module installation. Thanks!